# A/C Not working

Tags: ford, ac, focus, compressor

I drive a 2010 Ford Focus that blows warm air at full A/C. Today I purchased a A/C recharge kit, and attempted to recharge the A/C. Initially, when I attached the recharge kit (car running, A/C on full blast, doors open) I showed no pressure. I tried squeezing a little freon in (one quick pull of the trigger), and pressure jumped quickly to the green. Surprised, I tapped the trigger quickly once more, and saw the pressure rise again, to the high end of the green. Then the engine died. When I restarted the car, w/o A/C, it would run, until the moment I turned on A/C, which would stall the engine. So, I went out and released some pressure using the hose attachment. When I did, the car would run with A/C on, but no cold air.

Throughout the whole ordeal, it didn't look like the compressor ever engaged (belts spinning, but clutch never activated). So, I'm curious what caused the car to stall, and how I can fix the problem. Sounds like a compressor issue. Is there something I can do in my driveway to fix this? Or do I need to involve a professional?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! At this point I think I'd be looking to the professional. It would seem to me the compressor may be frozen, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I think you've knackered the A/C pump. This is quite easy to do with these 'Recharge Kits', as they provide no lubrication properties for the AC pumps. Some vehicles have separate bearings, whilst others use a different type of AC fluid that adds a lubricant.

Comment: This is actually weird, because A/C clutch should disengage when the RPM drops below idle. Apparently your whole compressor unit must be stuck. That's why it stalled - when you put enough gas, pressure sensor engaged the A/C clutch to enable compressor. Same story when you engaged the A/C manually (ie. with the button).  I'd change the A/C compressor but if you don't have much experience with it, it might be easier to let the professionals do it.